# Closed walks that don't contain cycles

Tags: graph-theory, induction

> Let F be a closed walk of length at least 2 that does not contain a
> cycle. Prove by induction that there's an edge that repeats.

I begin the induction process for a basis of 2 edges i.e V1,V2 so that a closed walk would be V1, e1, V2, e1, V1.

I'm having some trouble identifying the induction step. My reasoning suggests if it holds for k edges then it should also hold for k+1 edges. However I'm having some trouble making a solid statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image of a closed walk without a cycle is a connected graph with a cycle, hence a tree. Every tree has a leaf, so pick one and call it $v$. By definition of a leaf it has a unique incident edge $uv$. By definition of the graph as image of the walk we have that $uvu$ is a part of the walk and the edge $uv$ is contained twice.

In fact we can make the statement stronger: We can abbreviate the walk by deleting *every occurrence* of the part $uvu$. But this walk still is closed and doesn’t contain a cycle. So this walk and hence the original walk meets another edge at least twice. By induction *every* edge in the image of the walk is hit at least twice.